# Combine multiple dictionaries with the same schema

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries of unknown length and unknown - but consistent - schema, as follows. Note that the values are always lists of the same length.

```
res = [{'x': [2, 1], 'v': [49280, 536704]},
 {'x': [1, 4], 'v': [12336, 340000]},
 {'x': [5, 6], 'v': [524360, 151624]},
 {'x': [7, 1], 'v': [94280, 81968]},
 {'x': [1, 1], 'v': [241856, 335904]},
 {'x': [7, 7], 'v': [463016, 598040]},
 {'x': [2, 9], 'v': [606256, 422016]},
 {'x': [1, 1], 'v': [151680, 1237120]}]
```

Is there an efficient way to merge combine these together into a single dictionary? The final result for this example would be:

```
 {'x': [2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 2, 9, 1, 1], 
  'v': [49280, 536704, 12336, 340000, 524360, 151624, 94280, 81968, 241856, 335904, 463016, 598040, 606256, 422016, 151680, 1237120]}
```

**Working solution**

This works, but I wonder if a one-liner for this operation?

```
output_dct = {}
for dct in res:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        output_dct[k] = v if k not in output_dct.keys() else output_dct[k] + v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly better approach using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
output_dct = {}
for dct in res:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        output_dct.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

---

or using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
output_dct = defaultdict(list)
for dct in res:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        output_dct[k].extend(v)

print(output_dct)
```

**Output:**

```
{'x': [2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 2, 9, 1, 1], 
'v': [49280, 536704, 12336, 340000, 524360, 151624, 94280, 81968, 241856, 335904, 463016, 598040, 606256, 422016, 151680, 1237120]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner, you say?  To the comprehension-mobile!

```
>>> {k: sum((d[k] for d in res), []) for d in res for k in d}
{'x': [2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 2, 9, 1, 1], 'v': [49280, 536704, 12336, 340000, 524360, 151624, 94280, 81968, 241856, 335904, 463016, 598040, 606256, 422016, 151680, 1237120]}
```

(edit: practically speaking, I'd probably do this with a `defaultdict` like Rakesh did, because nested comprehensions are compact on the page but aren't necessarily obvious to other readers of the code.)